# What's the meaning of $\mathcal O_S$-algebra?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $(S,\mathcal O_S)$ be a scheme. What's the definition of $\mathcal O_S$-algebra?

Answer (score 1):

It's a sheaf  $\mathcal{A}$ of $\mathcal{O}_S$-modules on $S$ which is also a sheaf of rings, such that the $\mathcal{O}_S$-module map $\mathcal{O}_S \to \mathcal{A}$ induced by $1 \mapsto 1$ is a ring map.

(Equivalently, a sheaf of rings $\mathcal{A}$ on $S$ together with a ring homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_S \to \mathcal{A}$.)

Comment: (This answer is assuming that a "ring" is commutative with $1$ and that you implicitly are talking about commutative $\mathcal{O}_S$ algebras, as in e.g. Hartshorne's book. If you want them to be non-commutative, you need to add the condition that the ring homomorphism land in the center of $\mathcal{A}$.)

Comment: In the first paragraph of your above answer, how to show the structure of the sheaf $\mathcal A$ of $\mathcal O_S$-modules on $S$ can be induced by the ring homomorphism $\mathcal O_S\to \mathcal A$?